# Forward DM message to guild channel

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

I want to make that when my bot receives a direct message, it sends it to a channel in my guild. How do I achieve this?

I do know I have to use `if (message.channel.type == "dm") {}`, but how do I take what the bot receives and send it to a specific Server in a specific Channel?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to send the text, just send its content:

```
client.on("message", msg => {
  if (msg.channel.type == "dm") mychannel.send(msg.content); //mychannel is your TextChannel object
});
```

If you want to make that you can see the author & stuff like that you could use an embed (see how to build & send one [here](https://discordjs.guide/#/popular-topics/miscellaneous-examples?id=sending-an-embed)).

If you want to make like it's almost identical to someone's message, you could use a webhook:

```
guild.fetchWebhooks().then(webhooks => {
  let myhook = webhooks.find("placeholder");

  client.on("message", msg => {
    if (msg.channel.type == "dm") myhook.send(msg.content, {
      username: msg.author.username,
      avatarURL: msg.author.avatarURL,
    });
  });
});
```

Hope this helped, let me know if you have any other question

Comment: Can you explain what is `myChannel` ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj It's the guild's text channel where you want to send the message, as the author asked in the question

Comment: But I am not getting what is it's value. Is it just name of the channel ?

Comment: No, it's the object that represents the channel in discord.js